# Dynamic field retrieval from sobject in vf page

Tags: describesobject, visualforce, sobjecttype

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
```

from this we can retrieve all the fields but of account object but i want retrieve all the fields of any sobject.

I had accessed the sobjects by this---

```
List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values(); 
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
  list<String> fieldlabel=new list<String>();

   GlobalDescribeMap.put(fieldlabel,gd);
  //Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
   for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
    {
    if(f.getDescribe().isCreateable() && (!f.getDescribe().CustomSetting) &&  (f.getDescribe().keyPrefix!=null ||f.getDescribe().keyPrefix!='') && f.getDescribe().isUpdateable() && f.getDescribe().isQueryable() && f.getDescribe().isAccessible() && f.getDescribe().isUndeletable())                     
       {
       options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
       fieldlabel.add(f.getDescribe().getLabel());
      // system.debug('@@@'+fieldlabel);
   }
   }
    return options;
```

but not able to dynamically retrieve the fields.. please help

Answer (score 4):

The following code (that you can run in the Developer Console's "Execute Anonymous" window) illustrates how starting from a string containing the SObject type name you can get the detailed information about the fields. If all you want is the field names you only need to make the describe call on the `SObjectType` token. If you want more detailed information about the fields you need to also make describe calls on the `SObjectField` tokens.

```
// SObject type as a string
String sobTypeString = 'Contact';

// Get SObjectType token for the string
Map<String, SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
SObjectType sobType = gd.get(sobTypeString);

// Get detailed info
DescribeSObjectResult r = sobType.getDescribe();

// Field names immediately available
Set<String> fieldNames = r.fields.getMap().keySet();
System.debug('>>> fieldNames=' + fieldNames);

// Call field describe for more detailed info on each field
for (SObjectField f : r.fields.getMap().values()) {
    DescribeFieldResult rr = f.getDescribe();
    System.debug('>>> fieldDescribe=' + rr);
    System.debug('>>> fieldLabel=' + rr.getLabel());
}
```

Note that describe calls are subject to the platform's [governor limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm).

Comment: There are some known SalesForce issues which you may need to bare in mind with this approach. SF added an `OtherAddresses` field on `Contact` in API 30, this field gets returned when using `r.fields.getMap().values()` regardless of what API version you are using, see [issue details](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3FOAA0). [This](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC) is another similar issue relating to a new field that was added to all custom objects in API 28